# Trouble with clipping a GeoJSON polygon from a PNG raster tile in a Django Python app with rasterio

Tags: google-maps, clip, rasterio, png, django

I am currently working with a Django Python app that is associated with a PostgreSQL database where PostGIS is installed. There's a specific table in the database with a column of the polygon type, storing polygons.

To provide a bit more context, I have constructed a view that retrieves the GeoJSON polygon from the database using its id. The objective of this view is to compare each queried tile from my local server to determine whether the polygon intersects the raster tile. If an intersection occurs, the aim is to process the tile, clip it, save it to a temporary folder, and serve it to the front end.

The raster tiles I am working with are PNG images and include a color band for transparency. These images are stored in folders using z, x, y numbering in the path, and have been created with the MapTiler software. As per my understanding, the EPSG projection seems to align with that of Google Maps.

However, I'm currently experiencing some issues. The function I have written, which I'll detail below, is not successfully clipping the polygon as expected.

Here's the code of the function I wrote:

```py
import numpy as np
from rasterio.features import geometry_mask
from rasterio.transform import from_bounds
from shapely.geometry import mapping
from PIL import Image
from shapely.wkt import loads
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile

from my_app.my_app.settings import STATICFILES_DIRS


def clip_png_with_polygon(png_path, polygon, x, y, z, output_path):
    # Open the PNG file and convert it to a numpy array
    img = Image.open(png_path)
    raster = np.array(img)

    # Calculate the bounds of the tile in the Google Maps Mercator projection
    n = 2.0 ** z
    lon_deg = x / n * 360.0 - 180.0
    lat_rad = np.arctan(np.sinh(np.pi * (1 - 2 * y / n)))
    lat_deg = lat_rad * 180.0 / np.pi
    size = 360.0 / n
    left = lon_deg
    bottom = lat_deg
    right = lon_deg + size
    top = lat_deg + size

    # Create a rasterio Dataset object
    with MemoryFile() as memfile:
        with memfile.open(
                driver='GTiff',
                height=raster.shape[0],
                width=raster.shape[1],
                count=raster.shape[2],
                dtype=raster.dtype,
                crs='+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs',
                transform=from_bounds(left, bottom, right, top, raster.shape[1], raster.shape[0])
        ) as src:

            # Convert the polygon to a rasterio-compatible format
            shapes = [mapping(polygon)]

            # Create a mask from the polygon
            mask = geometry_mask(shapes, transform=src.transform, out_shape=(src.height, src.width), invert=True)

            # Clip the raster with the mask
            # clipped_raster = np.zeros_like(raster)
            # for band in range(src.count):
            #     if band == 3:  # Alpha channel
            #         clipped_raster[:, :, band] = raster[:, :, band]  # Preserve the alpha channel
            #     else:
            #         clipped_raster[:, :, band] = raster[:, :, band] * mask
            # v2

            # Clip the raster with the mask
            clipped_raster = raster.copy()  # Start with a copy of the original raster
            for band in range(src.count):
                if band == 3:  # Alpha channel
                    continue  # Don't change the alpha channel
                elif band == 0:  # Red channel
                    # Set the pixels inside the polygon area to maximum
                    clipped_raster[:, :, band] = np.where(mask, 255, clipped_raster[:, :, band])
                else:  # Green and blue channels
                    # Set the pixels inside the polygon area to minimum
                    clipped_raster[:, :, band] = np.where(mask, 0, clipped_raster[:, :, band])

    # Save the clipped raster to a new PNG file
    Image.fromarray(clipped_raster).save(output_path)
```

here the data to run the example

```py
x = 66678
y = 44071
z = 17
wkt_string = "POLYGON ((3.13871537 50.66826049, 3.1388816 50.66807065, 3.13898343 50.66795865, 3.13904183 50.66791025, 3.13918111 50.66783146, 3.13921555 50.66781343, 3.13879923 50.66730657, 3.13877227 50.66727715, 3.13867493 50.66714331, 3.13843083 50.66680445, 3.13776293 50.66705789, 3.13871537 50.66826049))"
polygon = loads(wkt_string)
png_path = 'path_to_png/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
output_path = 'path_to_tmp_folder/output.png'
clip_png_with_polygon(png_path, polygon, x, y, z, output_path)
```

The front end use google map code, a query is made to my view to query raster tile of a Google map layer, that are in the top of the base map, and the polygon is on top of the layer:

```js
        var tileLayer = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
            getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {

                return "/tile/{{ town|lower }}/{{ year }}/{{ geojson_id }}/" + zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png";
            },
            tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
            isPng: true,
            name: "My Custom Layer",
            maxZoom: 19
        });
```

will query my Django view as :

```py
# the database class model
class ParcelleGeojson(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    geometry = PolygonField()
    properties = HStoreField()
    commune_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    map_date = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'parcelle_geojson_save'

    def to_geojson(self):
        feature = {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "geometry": json.loads(self.geometry.json),
            "properties": self.properties,
            "id": str(self.id)
        }
        return feature


def tile_to_bbox(z, x, y):
    n = 2.0 ** z
    lon_deg = x / n * 360.0 - 180.0
    lat_rad = math.atan(math.sinh(math.pi * (1 - 2 * y / n)))
    lat_deg = math.degrees(lat_rad)
    next_lat_rad = math.atan(math.sinh(math.pi * (1 - 2 * (y + 1) / n)))
    next_lat_deg = math.degrees(next_lat_rad)
    next_lon_deg = ((x + 1) / n * 360.0) - 180.0
    return (lon_deg, next_lon_deg, lat_deg, next_lat_deg)


# the django view
class TileView(View):
    def get(self, request, town, year, geojson_id, z, x, y):


        tile_path_input = f'path_to_static_app/img/map/{town}/{year}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        tile_path_interim = f'path_to_static_app/tmp_raster/{town}/{year}/{z}/{x}/{y}_interim.png'
        tile_path_output = f'path_to_static_app/tmp_raster/{town}/{year}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'

        # Check if the processed tile already exists
        if os.path.exists(tile_path_output):
           return FileResponse(open(tile_path_output, 'rb'), as_attachment=True, filename=os.path.basename(tile_path_output))

        parcelle_geojson_obj = ParcelleGeojson.objects.get(id=geojson_id)

        # Define your polygon (this would come from your database in reality)
        polygon = parcelle_geojson_obj.geometry[0]
        polygon = Polygon(polygon)

        # Get the bounds of the tile
        tile_bounds = box(*tile_to_bbox(z, x, y))
        
        # transparent image (256x256px)
        none_file = f'path_to_static/img/map/none.png'

        intersect = tile_bounds.intersects(polygon)

        if not tile_bounds.intersects(polygon):
            # If not, return a transparent image
            return FileResponse(open(none_file, 'rb'), as_attachment=True, filename=os.path.basename(none_file))

        else:
            if not os.path.exists(tile_path_input):
                # if not exist return tranparent image
                print("not exist - sent None")
                return FileResponse(open(none_file, 'rb'), as_attachment=True, filename=os.path.basename(none_file))

            # [ FUNCTION TO CLIP THE IMAGE HERE]
            return FileResponse(open(tile_path_input, 'rb'), as_attachment=True,
                                filename=os.path.basename(tile_path_input))
        # return the clipped image
        return FileResponse(open(tile_path_output, 'rb'), as_attachment=True, filename=os.path.basename(tile_path_output))
```

Also you can see that the tile_to_bbox is a bit different, because i tried different things.

the parameter used for testing :

```py
from shapely.wkt import loads

x = 66678
y = 44071
z = 17
wkt_string = "POLYGON ((3.13871537 50.66826049, 3.1388816 50.66807065, 3.13898343 50.66795865, 3.13904183 50.66791025, 3.13918111 50.66783146, 3.13921555 50.66781343, 3.13879923 50.66730657, 3.13877227 50.66727715, 3.13867493 50.66714331, 3.13843083 50.66680445, 3.13776293 50.66705789, 3.13871537 50.66826049))"
polygon = loads(wkt_string)
png_path = 'tile.png'
output_path = 'output.png'
clip_png_with_polygon(png_path, polygon, x, y, z, output_path)
```

To give you a more comprehensive understanding of the problem, I am also attaching an image of an example tile and the coordinates of the polygon. I will also provide an image of the desired result.

[image: The raster image before with transparency]

what it looks actually in my app :

[image: wanted result]

And what I wanted in result:

[image: image actual within the google map]

I've searched extensively for solutions and tried several adjustments to my code, but haven't been able to resolve the issue yet. What might be going wrong and how can I correct it?

## EDIT - 12/06/2023

I come with this solution but I don't know why it's not working with PNG in RGBA (transparency) - Is there a way to do it more simply ?

```py
import math

import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rasterio
from rasterio.mask import mask
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterio.transform import from_origin
from shapely import wkt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon


def num2deg(xtile, ytile, zoom):
    n = 1 << zoom
    lon_deg = xtile / n * 360.0 - 180.0
    lat_rad = math.atan(math.sinh(math.pi * (1 - 2 * ytile / n)))
    lat_deg = math.degrees(lat_rad)
    return lat_deg, lon_deg


def get_bbox(xtile, ytile, zoom):
    top_left_lat, top_left_lon = num2deg(xtile, ytile, zoom)
    bottom_right_lat, bottom_right_lon = num2deg(xtile + 1, ytile + 1, zoom)

    return top_left_lon, top_left_lat, bottom_right_lon, bottom_right_lat


# Tile coordinates
z = 17
x = 66678
y = 44071

# Polygon string
polygon_string = "POLYGON ((3.13871537 50.66826049, " \
                 "3.1388816 50.66807065, " \
                 "3.13898343 50.66795865, " \
                 "3.13904183 50.66791025, " \
                 "3.13918111 50.66783146, " \
                 "3.13921555 50.66781343, " \
                 "3.13879923 50.66730657, " \
                 "3.13877227 50.66727715, " \
                 "3.13867493 50.66714331, " \
                 "3.13843083 50.66680445, " \
                 "3.13776293 50.66705789, " \
                 "3.13871537 50.66826049))"

# Tile path
tile_path = "./17/66678/44071_interim.png"

# Convert the polygon string to a Shapely geometry object
polygon_geom = wkt.loads(polygon_string)
gdf_polygone = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs="EPSG:4326", geometry=[polygon_geom])

# get the bbox of the raster tile from his x, y, z value
bbox = get_bbox(x, y, z)
polygon_bbox_raster_tile = Polygon([(bbox[0], bbox[1]), (bbox[2], bbox[1]), (bbox[2], bbox[3]), (bbox[0], bbox[3])])
gdf_bbox_raster_tile = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs="EPSG:4326", geometry=[polygon_bbox_raster_tile])

# Load raster tile PNG file
with rasterio.open(tile_path) as src:
    tile = src.read()  # read the first band


# Flip the tile along the y-axis
#tile = np.flipud(tile)

# Calculate the size of the pixels
x_pixel = (bbox[2] - bbox[0]) / 256
y_pixel = (bbox[3] - bbox[1]) / 256

# Create the transform
transform = from_origin(bbox[0], bbox[3], x_pixel, y_pixel)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot the tile using the transform
show(tile, transform=transform, ax=ax, origin='lower')


# Plot the polygons
gdf_polygone.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='red')
gdf_bbox_raster_tile.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='blue')

# Plot the points and annotate
for idx, point in enumerate(polygon_geom.exterior.coords):
    ax.scatter(*point, color='black', s=3)  # s is the size of the dot
    ax.annotate(f'{idx}: {point}', (point[0], point[1]), fontsize=8)

ax.invert_yaxis()

ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')
plt.show()
```

Wich produce (I moove it a little bit to the left):

[image]

```py
# Try to convert the PNG to TIFF with raster io


dataset = rasterio.open(tile_path, 'r')
bands = [1, 2, 3]
data = dataset.read(bands)
transform = rasterio.transform.from_bounds(bbox[0], bbox[3], bbox[2], bbox[1], data.shape[1], data.shape[2])
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}

tiff_path = './app_name/app_name/static/tmp_raster/clipped_raster.tif'
output_path = './app_name/app_name/static/tmp_raster/clipped_raster_2.tif'

with rasterio.open(tiff_path, 'w', driver='GTiff',
                   width=data.shape[1], height=data.shape[2],
                   count=3, dtype=data.dtype, nodata=0,
                   transform=transform, crs=crs) as dst:
    dst.write(data, indexes=bands)


def rasterio_clip(geodataframe, raster_path, output_path):
    shapes = geodataframe.geometry

    for i, shape in enumerate(shapes):
        with rasterio.open(raster_path) as src:
            out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, [shape.__geo_interface__], crop=True)
            out_meta = src.meta

        out_meta.update({
            "driver": "GTiff",
            "height": out_image.shape[1],
            "width": out_image.shape[2],
            "transform": out_transform,
            "nodata": 0,
        })

        with rasterio.open(output_path, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
            dest.write(out_image)


rasterio_clip(gdf_polygone, tiff_path, output_path)
```

Create the desired output as :

[image]